# Combining dictionaries with a particular key: Python

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I have the following dictionaries generated using for loop and I would to combine and dump them into one `YAML` file.

dict1

```
{'name': 'test',
 'version': '0011 * *? *',

 'datasets': [{
   'dataset': 'dataset_a',
   'match_on': ['code'],
   'columns': {'include': ['aa',
     'bb',
     'cc']}}]
}
```

dict2

```
{'name': 'test',
 'version': '0011 * *? *',

 'datasets': [{
   'dataset': 'dataset_b',
   'match_on': ['code'],
   'columns': {'include': ['aaa',
     'bbb',
     'ccc']}}]
}
```

The dictionaries have common values on `name` and `version` keys. So, I would like to put it as common but they have differences on the `datasets` key. The desired output look like the following

combined_dict

```
{'name': 'test',
 'version': '0011 * *? *',

 'datasets': [{
   'dataset': 'dataset_a',
   'match_on': ['code'],
   'columns': {'include': ['aa',
     'bb',
     'cc']}}]

'datasets': [{
   'dataset': 'dataset_b',
   'match_on': ['code'],
   'columns': {'include': ['aaa',
     'bbb',
     'ccc']}}]
}
```

To achieve this, I have tried the following.

```
combined_dict= {**dict1,**dict2}

with open('combined_dict.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(updated_dict , outfile, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: can't have the same key twice in the same dict

Comment: Okay, I see. So, there is no any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, you cannot do what you want since the key in the dictionary has to be unique. What you can do is add an element to the list associated with the key "datasets", in order to obtain something like this:

```py
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0011 * *? *",
    "datasets": [
        {
            "dataset": "dataset_a",
            "match_on": ["code"],
            "columns": {"include": ["aa", "bb", "cc"]},
        },
        {
            "dataset": "dataset_b",
            "match_on": ["code"],
            "columns": {"include": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]},
        },
    ],
}
```

This is the code to do that:

```py
combined_dict = dict1.copy()
combined_dict["datasets"].extend(dict2["datasets"])
```

If you want to modify in-place `dict1`, just replace `combined_dict` with `dict1`